# Get utf8 DOM from utf8 file

Tags: php, utf-8

I have the following code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function getSource($url)
{
    if (!function_exists('curl_init'))
    {
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

$source = getSource('http://www.website.com/');
var_dump($source); die();
```

And the file itself is in UTF-8. The thing is the UTF-8 characters of the output are not displayed properly. Instead they are shown as question marks, or some other trash.

And the only thing to solve this that I found out is to encode the file as ISO-8859-1. But I don't want that. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The value you pass to [`CURLOPT_ENCODING`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is *(a)* invalid, and *(b)* meaningless, in that it doesn't force Curl to translate the content it fetches into the encoding you want.  If the remote site returns ISO-8859-1, then you have to translate that to UTF-8 yourself.

`CURLOPT_ENCODING` is used to accept the `Accept-Encoding:` header when fetching a page.  Valid values are `"identity"`,`"deflate"`, and `"gzip"`.  As you can see, it has no meaning for the character-set encoding.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning some ways of doing the conversion - `mb_convert_encoding` and `iconv` come to mind.